# Several Questions About "Prioritized Experience Replay"

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I have 3 questions about "Prioritized Experience Buffer" as  described in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.05952).

1. what's the point of the importance sampling (IS)?
   I'll explain - I understand that:

   a. when we prioritize some samples, we change the distribution.

   b. by doing that, we change the excepted value and therefore the
   final solution the agent will converge to.

   but, isn't that an issue only **if the first solution is better**? the first solution is
   based on uniform sampling, and to me it sounds like there is no reason to think this is a
   more "real" distribution, since these samples were collected using older policy. samples
   that are common in the buffer can be very rare given the current policy.
2. even if we do want to correct the distribution, why do we need the IS? the authors start
   with some beta and slowly raising it to 1, therefore completely compensating for the
   bias. can't we just remove the IS, start with an alpha of 0.6 and slowly lower it
   to 0?
3. this one is not related to IS. the authors acknowledge that updating each priority after
   each update to the agent is too computationally expensive and time consuming. therefore,
   they only update the priority for the samples they learn from. but as the agent learns,
   the priorities of all of the samples that were not learned from for a while becomes
   outdated. how come this improvement to the uniform replay buffer improve learning after all?

Answer (score 1):

1. no, by doing that you change the state distribution, which causes a ton of problems, like the change in value estimation... which means that if you don't prioritize, your policy might learn states on which it might never see again, because it already knows that they are very bad
2. the IS is the correction
3. the agent will learn the Q value for the starting and ending state, thus the update will pretty much produce a 0 TD error, causing no issue, and the new priority will be close to 0